# How can I hide any DOM element

Tags: jquery, dom

I want to hide any element that is clicked. For example, if `<p></p>` is clicked it should hide, or if `<div></div>` is clicked it should hide. I tried using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

However, this hides all the elements if one element is clicked.

How can I achieve what I described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event will bubble up the DOM until it reaches the `document`, and then everything is hidden. You can stop that bubbling by using `stopPropagation` on the event:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Also note that it's not a good idea to add an event handler to *every* element in the DOM as there could be *thousands*. Instead, bind a single handler to the `document` using event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/38uvp1dt/)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate way of `e.stopPropagation();`, You could also hide only the targeted element:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).hide();
});
```

Comment: This would also work well with event delegation: `$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).hide();
});`

Comment: Agree, I was just showing an alternate way to achieve the same result. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This works too. I will learn about the target element :)